# Merge two json arrays

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have to array i want to merge them in one array by same id. So every two array have same id should be merged

Case 1:

```
 { 
    "id":1212,
    "instructor":"william",
     ...
 }
```

Case 2:

```
[ 
     {
        "id":1212,
        "name":"accounting",
         ...
     },
     { 
        "id":1212,
        "name":"finance",
        ...
     }
]
```

I need the result to be :

```
{        
    "id": 1212,
    "instructor": "william",
    "Courses": [
         { 
            "id":1212,
            "name":"accounting",
             ...
         },
         { 
            "id":1212,
            "name":"finance",
             ...
         }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking isn't merging, but here is how you can do that.

```js
const instructors = [{ "id":1212, "instructor":"william", }];
const courses = [ 
  { "id":1212, "name":"accounting" },
  { "id":1212, "name":"finance" }
];

const expected = [{ "id":1212, "instructor":"william", "courses": [
  { "id":1212, "name":"accounting" },
  { "id":1212, "name":"finance" }
]}];

const composed = instructors.map(ins => {
  const ret = {...ins};
  ret.courses = courses.filter(cou => cou.id === ins.id);
  return ret;
});

console.log(composed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var finArr;
var course = [];
use forEach loop  javascript get all value  in put your value instead of varid and varname
course.push({"id":varid,"name":varname});
finArr = {"id":variableId,"instructor":variablename,"Courses":course}
```

Comment: Could you extend this answer to explain how this is relevant to OP issue?